# Specific elements not being found in detox js if metro bundler not running

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, detox, metro-bundler

I have started testing in detox, and find that I get the `Test Failed: No elements found for “MATCHER(id == “code-input”)”` error on one test. Other tests have similar matchers, and this is on the third screen of the app so it's not a navigation issue.

When I run metro bundler before running the tests, I don't see this error. On the emulated device, the input successfully completes. However, instead I get the dreaded sync issue that goes into an endless loop:

```
The app is busy with the following tasks:
• 1 enqueued native timers:
  - Timer #1:
    + Fire date: none.
    + Time until fire: 0.000.
    + Repeat interval: 0.
    + Is recurring: YES.
• There are 1 work items pending on the dispatch queue: "Main Queue (<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread>)".
```

Here is the very simple test:

```
it("should successfully submit verification code", async () => {
    const codeInput = element(by.id("code-input"));
    await codeInput.typeText(VERIFICATION_CODE);
});
```

I have added `expect` statements too, and it doesn't ever get past the third line because of the `MATCHER` failure.

I guess my question is about how this discrepancy can happen, and (subsequently) what may cause the loop? Because it's jsut that one element that doesn't get found - whereas 5 or 6 others do get found. Plus on the emulator the test runner inputs the code jsut fine. It's really inconsistent behaviour that I don't understand at all.

Answer (score 0):

The app needed to be bundled via `react-native bundle` (if you have rn cli) first. This updated the main.jsbundle that ios relies on to build the app.